# What am I doing wrong with my function within this django view?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This should be easy...  I'm taking a course and the way this is structured the view.py file can stand alone for the purpose of this quiz - it's more like a challenge.  Ok, so the request is this:
"Now, create a view named article_list that selects all Article instances and returns an HttpResponse like "There are 5 articles." Be sure to use the len() of the Article queryset to get the number of articles."

As a point of reference, the first part works. Anyway, the view.py file looks like this (The first part is where I import Article... guess I don't need the render import.):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Article

# Write your views here
def article_list(request):
  articles = Article.objects.all()
  article_count = articles.len()
  output = "There are {} articles.".format(str(article_count))
  return HttpResponse(output)
```

I'm not sure if the len function and/or the str function should be chained like this or if they should wrap the objects.  I tried putting articles.len().str() and that didn't seem to work.
Thanks in advance for any help,
Bruce

Comment: I know you can't do anything about it, but note that the instruction to use len() is horribly misguided, because it evaluates the entire queryset and retrieves all the articles for no reason. Since you only want to count them, in your case you should use the `count()` method instead.

Comment: That might then work in giving the response from the function.  I think the challenges try to run the functions and see if they get what is expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
article_count = len(articles)
output = "There are {} articles.".format(article_count)
```

len is a function that you call on a object and the format method already calls the str method for you.

Comment: @Pynchia you'll need to explain why. This is the correct answer to the problem the OP is having with his instructions.

Comment: This is the right way to do the wrong thing you're being asked to do in your instructions.

Comment: @Pynchia, what other person?  Sometimes learning a new framework involves starting by just sending a simple text value to the browser, which we would never do, we'd send a html page.

Comment: This was a tough decision for choosing best answer.  Both this and the next are equally good, so it was a toss up.

Comment: Are there cases where one does need to str before giving something to the format function?  Are there cases where format will not call str?

Answer (score 4):

Using `.all()` just to count the number of records introduces an [unnecessary overhead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated):

> If you only need to determine the number of records in the set (and
>   don’t need the actual objects), it’s much more efficient to handle a
>   count at the database level using SQL’s SELECT COUNT(*). Django
>   provides a count() method for precisely this reason.

Directly get the `count` from the database using [`.count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count):

```
articles_count = Article.objects.count()
output = "There are {} articles.".format(article_count)
```

This is a generally accepted way to count the records unless the record instances are actually needed, or, if there is a specific requirement, as in your case:

> Be sure to use the `len()` of the Article queryset to get the number of articles.

Taking into account how the problem was stated, @Andoni's answer should be accepted.

Comment: While this is true, OP's instructions (presumably some kind of coursework) specifically told him to do so.

Comment: Yes, to get the count, it seems not to be necessary to get the list of articles.  This approach might pass - or work - even though it is not doing what is instructed.  Another training site let me solve a problem without doing exactly what was requested.  It was udacity.  I was using something more efficient but we had not gotten to it yet.  Sometimes I view courses even when they might seem a bit basic or targeted to someone less experienced - many times I realize there is something I was lacking in my understanding.

Comment: This second approach actually worked.  The system accepted it.  So, they similarly must run the code and see if the answer matches.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: Don't use len() on QuerySets if all you want to do is determine the number of records in the set. It's much more efficient to handle a count at the database level, using SQL's SELECT COUNT(*), and Django provides a count() method for precisely this reason. See count() below.

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)